# Do all TypeScript classes that intend to be used by other classes need to be explicitly exported and imported?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular10

Do all classes that intend to be used by other classes need to be explicitly exported and imported?

I currently have a project that I upgraded from Angular 8 to Angular 10 and noticed a lot of errors THAT WERE NOT THERE BEFORE that may be related to either poor design or a faulty compiler (I assume it's bad design I'm a novice at TypeScript, maybe the new compilers are pickier?). For every class that I was referencing that didn't use an export/import statement, I now get the errors shown below after upgrading my project to Angular 10. This could be fixed by making every single class have the keyword "export" on it, but that would mean I'm explicitly exporting with the intention of importing where needed. However, these classes were intended to be in the global scope of the application and I wanted every other module to see these without having to explicitly import them since these helper classes and types are used everywhere. However, it doesn't look like what I want to do is possible after noticing these errors. So in summary- do I need to explicitly export and import all the classes that I intend to reference?

Old code

```
 class Person {
        public first:string;
        public last:string;
        constructor(
            first:string,
            last:string,
            )
        {
            this.first = first;
            this.last = last;
        }
        get fullName(): string {
            return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
        }
    }
```

New code

```
export class Person { //I would rather not use the export keyword since Person should be used everywhere
    public first:string;
    public last:string;
    constructor(
        first:string,
        last:string,
        )
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
    get fullName(): string {
        return this.first + ' ' + this.last;
    }
}
```

Referencing Class:

```
// import { Person } from '../sharedTypes/person'; //needed if I use the export in the Person class
export class PurchaseOrder {
    public name: string;
    public poChargeNumber: ChargeNumber;
    public siteLocation: Address;
    public deliverTo: Person;
    public vendor: Vendor;
    public lineItems: LineItem[];
    constructor(
        chargeNum: ChargeNumber,
        siteLocation: Address,
        deliverTo: Person,
        lineItems: LineItem[],
        )
    {
        this.poChargeNumber = chargeNum;
        this.siteLocation = siteLocation;
        this.deliverTo = deliverTo;
        if (lineItems === null || lineItems === undefined)
            this.lineItems = new Array<LineItem>();
        else
            this.lineItems = lineItems;
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
src/app/purchaseorder-doc/purchaseOrder.ts:13:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ChargeNumber'.

13         chargeNum: ChargeNumber,
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/purchaseorder-doc/purchaseOrder.ts:14:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Address'.

14         siteLocation: Address,
                         ~~~~~~~
src/app/purchaseorder-doc/purchaseOrder.ts:15:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Person'.

m15         deliverTo: Person,
```

Comment: I’m not an Angular person so I genuinely don’t understand how it was working properly before the upgrade!  Were you doing something to put them in the global scope, or just assumed they’d end up there?  As a rule of thumb if something is not exported it can only be used in that particular file.

Comment: Did you have `export` on `PurchaseOrder` previously? It makes sense to me that it would yell about that since the compiler doesn't know if the eventual importer of `PurchaseOrder` has access to the global classes or not. Basically, I think you either have to use `import/eport` everywhere, or nowhere.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I'm not sure if it was just not as strict? It looks like ending up at the global scope is expected behavior? Please correct me if I'm wrong though as I'm a novice. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html
"In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well)."

Comment: @Goku thanks for the link, TIL.   I was not aware of that rule and it’s definitely not a common practice judging by the other comments.  What I would do is have a directory for all of your basic types and classes.  Re-export all of them from the index file of the directory.  You still have to import, but you can do multiple imports at once.  import { ChargeNumber, Address, Person} from “./core”

Comment: @LindaPaiste I'll definitely try that as that sounds much more concise in the long run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely use the import / export mechanism.

In the old days, JavaScript developers would write code that put variables / classes into the global scope, e.g. like this:

```
window.SomeClass = SomeClass
```

There is also the infamous implicit global, that is caught by strict mode:

```
// Globally available in the window!
myVar = 'my-Value'
```

With frameworks like Angular available today, I would definitely consider this a bad practice and only resort to it in special cases where no other solution is available.

Comment: So i need an export in every class that is called by other classes? I'm not sure why it worked before, It looks like ending up at the global scope is executed behavior? Please correct me if I'm wrong though as I'm a novice. typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level import or export is considered a module. Conversely, a file without any top-level import or export declarations is treated as a script whose contents are available in the global scope (and therefore to modules as well).

Comment: I must say that I never tried using typescript this way. Every IDE would mark a non-imported class/function/variable as an error. Also what would happen if you define something with the same name twice? I can only advice against it, even if it worked at some point.

Comment: "*Yes, you must use the import / export mechanism.*" - no, certainly not, but using modules is of course better than writing scripts that put everything in the global scope. TypeScript supports both.